# Facebook Permission Dialog doesn't prompt

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'm creating an  Android App that ask the user for this permissions: Default Login permission + user_friends + publish_action.

In my first activity i did the Login + ask the "user_friends" permission and work great.

Now in my Second Activity i want to ask for the "publish_action" permission after a AlertDialog choice.
The problem is that **i never been promped for the "publish_action" box, the app skip the request and go ahead calling another Activity (Leaderboards)**

Here is my Second Activity:

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
final Context context = this;

//stuff   

b_exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View V)
        {

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.salva_dati))
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.si), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {

                                    askForFBPublishPerm();

                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                                    editor.clear();
                                    editor.apply();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Leaderboard.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);   // IT START WITHOUT ASK ME THE PERMISSION
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
 }

 void askForFBPublishPerm(){
    Log.d("perm", "asking for the permissions");  //I  SEE THAT LOG BUT NOTHING MORE AFTER THAT LINE
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this,Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d("perm", "SUCCESS");//I DONT SEE THAT LOG
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancelled while asking publish permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("perm", "cancelled while asking publish permission");
            //I DONT SEE THAT LOG
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error occurred while asking publish permission!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("perm", "error occurred while asking publish permission!");  //I DONT SEE THAT LOG

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
}
```

In my Log i see that askForFBPublishPerm() as been called but it never enter in onSuccess() or onCancel() or onError().

I also get reviewed my app by Facebook and they gave me the "publish_action" permission.

**This "publish_action" request dont work and i dont know why**, someone can help me? Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle your callbackManager in onActivityResult. Just apply this code.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // this line is required
}
```

Comment: i added but got the same result.... no "publish_action" permission have been requested, it just continue to the next Activity (Leaderboard) without asking anithing

Comment: I have compiled your code. Only this was missing is the onActivityResult part. Disable your intent feature for a while, add a Toast in the onSuccess method in registerCallback and see if the Toast is being called. Also, make sure you are not declaring onActivityResult method inside onCreate method. In that case, you will get an error in @Override annotation above onActivityResult.

Comment: I tried, when i canceled the new Activity call it prompt the permission request fine! So now i copied and pasted the new call Intent in the Onsuccess() method. IT WORK,is the right way for do that? because seems so Thanks btw!

Comment: Yes, you should change your activity after you get the callback result. I missed that part. Nice to see you figured that out Cheers!